# PHP Codeigniter - How to save image to a folder

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to know, how to save a post image to folder in codeigniter

Comment: What have you tried and what version of codeigniter are you using?

Comment: first thing you do is visit the docs or any of the multitude of tutorials on how to do this

Answer (score 0):

```
 function addImage() {
if (!is_dir('./Uploads/')) {
    mkdir('./Uploads/', 0777, TRUE);
}
if (!empty($_FILES['image'])) {
    $config['upload_path'] = './Uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width'] = '1024';
    $config['max_height'] = '768';
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $config['file_name'] = date('U') . '_' . $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        print_r($error);
        die;
    } else {
        if ($this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
            $image_data = $this->upload->data();
            $full_path = $config['file_name'];
            $insert["image"] = $full_path;
            $insertId = $this->data_model->add_data($insert, 'tableName');

        }
    }
}
```